# Add CSS to pages through Admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.4

I am working on a site where our front end developers want to add CSS files to specific pages through the Admin (in effect, certain Admin driven pages will have special CSS). We are not using the built-in LESS setup that Magento has.

So far, they've tried the following (in **Content > Pages > Edit Page**):

[image: Edit Page Layout]

This "works" in the sense that the css file is in the `<head/>` and gets loaded. The issue is that we also have this in our `default_head_blocks.xml` file:
[image: default_head_blocks.xml]

When Magento combines all of the xml, the resulting css files are ordered as follows:

[image: Snippet of CSS files]

This causes the cascade to grab the CSS in an undesired order and the page doesn't display as we need. I've tried playing around with the `<move/>` XML action to no avail.

We've had little to no luck with finding a solution. I found this question, [What is the proper way of positioning/ordering CSS files in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94769/what-is-the-proper-way-of-positioning-ordering-css-files-in-magento-2), but the answer here is not an option at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html) from the dev docs will be helpful as it is regarding component load order but it does also mention it can be used with CSS and LESS.

Comment: I'm not sure it is helpful, unfortunately. I'm not sure how I would use `<sequence>` through the Admin itself. Thanks though!

Comment: I take it that will only work if you're creating your own component. That was my only hope damn it! Hopefully someone has an answer.

Comment: I haven't played around with M2 but have you tried something like `<referenceContainer name="before.head.end">....<referenceContainer>` place your resource in there?

Comment: You might find [this article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_css_layout_woes) by Alan Storm interesting.

Comment: I just finished the first version of an extension that allows you to order *css* tags with an *order* attribute. Checkout my answer below and the new extension! Let me know if any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento2 has no built-in mechanism for this so I decided to treat it as an opportunity to write my first Magento2 extension. The [Quickshiftin\Assetorderer extension](https://github.com/quickshiftin/mage2-ordered-assets) is now available on GitHub!

Once you have the extension installed you can specify an *order* attribute in your *css* XML tags.

```
<head>
  <css src="css/page/home.css" order="100"/>
</head>
```

You can also use the *order* attribute in layout XML files such as `default_head_blocks.xml`. Any *css* tags you don't specify an *order* for are treated as if they have an *order* of 1.

Comment: It really hurts that this is the answer (because it shouldn't require an extension to be able to reorder assets...), but once we got it configured, it worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: Totally hear you on that and glad to have helped! Checkout that Alan Storm article I linked to under your question. It's a long read (I skimmed some of it), but interesting in that Magento2 adds some complexity on top of the layout updates that Magento1 had. The *head* section in particular seems to be less flexible than it was in the former version.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the articles that spurred the question, because we couldn't figure out how to get it to work as desired.

Comment: As per my experience it is perfect solution and working for me. But some time it not working due to server configuration and I faced it. NO NEED TO INSTALLED ANY KIND OF MODULE FOR ORDER CSS. It is default solutions for 2.0.x you just need to add order="Number".

Comment: Rather than a downvote @VikramKumar you might consider adding another answer where you demonstrate the working behavior out of the box, as I and many other folks have not been able to get it to work, hence the creation and upvotes for this module on github.

Comment: Please update your answer and remove module link because no need to installed ant module for just order CSS. Without updating your answer I not able to change anything.

Comment: @VikramKumar Please re-read my last comment...

Comment: @quickshiftin update your answer than only i can remove my downvote. I try but getting error like "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."