# Magento2 CSS give order

Tags: magento2, css

For a specific page, i have a plugin css to be added, i have some css added in my **default.xml**.

From a specific handle i.e `cms_index_index.xml`, i want to insert my plugin css at between already included css.

Is there a before, after, order in

```
<css src="css/ie-8.css" />
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but someone asked a related question [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112028/add-css-to-pages-through-admin) so it's worth keeping an eye on that to. They were asking the same question but for XML in the admin, so if there is a fix it should hopefully apply to both questions.