# Magento 2 : How to add custom css for adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, css

I need to add `CSS` file for Admin side in my custom module. How can I add this for Admin (back-end) only ?

Comment: regarding Krishna ijjada's answer: I also needed to add registration.php And im not sure if module.xml is required also.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1 Create a module for example `Vendor/Module`, this _means a fully working module, including `registration.php` file etc.

2 Create a new file `view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml` in the module:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
         <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css"/>
       </head>
    </page>
```

3. Add .css file in web folder as below path:

`view/adminhtml/web/css/test.css`

Run below commands and check.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

## Optional - check css load order:

**Note: css file load order might mean that your styles do not take effect, as `styles.css` gets loaded *after* these files.**

***This only works `~Magento 2.3 (tested on Magento 2.3.5)`.***

For example: adding order to 999, ensuring that it _should be one of the last `media=all` items:

```
<css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css order="999" />
```

> For additional information (for instance for older versions) on ordering: [See this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94769/what-is-the-proper-way-of-positioning-ordering-css-files-in-magento-2)

Comment: Hello, I am trying to add `<css src="Magento_Catalog::catalog/category-selector.css"/>` in my custom module, but it is showing 404 error in console.

Comment: in this example, Vendor_Module is the applied theme name only or we can take out new module also ? @Krishna ijjada

Comment: I just need to add one css file and somehow the css is not being added when I see in browser.
I need no css except the required one so I am removing the `css/styles.css`, and doing `<referenceContainer name="header" remove="true" />
   <referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true" />
   <referenceContainer name="logo" remove="true" />
   <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
   <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
`.
Any idea what am I missing...?

Answer (score 23):

Magento 2 uses less file so you can also use less type as follows below step.

Create new file at `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/source/_module.less`

after that run below command from root directory and check

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I need to add .less file to use less variables like @icon-help__content; I want this less file to be loaded after the other files are loaded what is the proper way to do this.

Comment: This has to be considered the correct answer.

Comment: am I the only for who neither this and the marked answer post doesn't work ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer can still be improved. With `default.xml` you will add the file to * every * admin page. This may not be the desired behavior.

Use appropriate controller handle:

```
view/adminhtml/layout/your_controller_path.xml
```

System configuration handle:

```
view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

TO ADD CUSTOM CSS OR JS IN ADMIN

Step 1: Create a module for example Vendor/Module

Step 2: Create a new file view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml in the module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
layout="admin-1column" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/
page_configuration.xsd">

  <head>

    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css"/>

    <script src="Vendor_Module::js/test.js"/>

  </head>

</page>
```

Step 3: Add .css file and add js file in web folder as below path

view/adminhtml/web/css/test.css

view/adminhtml/web/js/test.js