# How to change Magento 2 backend color?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, backend

In **Magento 2** every thing is in orange color, the color code is `#eb5202`.

I want to change this color to another **color**

How could I change this color?

or

Which file I have to modify?

Comment: Possible solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137439/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-css-for-adminhtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 : How to add custom css for adminhtml?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137439/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-css-for-adminhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/source/variables/_colors.less, it defines colours that used in backend.

Override in theme file:
app/design/adminhtml/**Vendor**/**themeName**/web/css/source/variables/_colors.less

Run this:

```
$ rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
$ rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```