# how to add custom css for a specific admin role in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4

I want to add some custom css for all of the admin pages for a **specific admin role**. I tried some methods but none of them worked.

Comment: which specific page do you want to add CSS?

Comment: on product listing page.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137439/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-css-for-adminhtml

Comment: @Priya no this won't work as i want to add css for a specific admin role not for all.

Answer (score 0):

Add css file in admin

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
         <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css"/>
       </head>
    </page>
```

Comment: Could you specify where your code should be added ? Also, I think this kind of instruction will add a CSS file for everyone. You will not be able to add it only for a specific admin role.

Comment: @Cladiuss yes thats the main challenge here.