# Load Custom CSS After style-l.css For Home Page

Tags: magento2.2, css, custom-theme

I am using below code to include my custom CSS file in home page only:

File: `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

This includes the `css/home/slider.css` file in the HTML but which loads before `style-l.css` and after `style-m` files included by Magento. I need my CSS file to be included after the `style-m.css` and `style-l.css` loaded by Magento.

Magento loads its style CSS files via `default_head_blocks.xml` which I believe if I use in my case, it will load my custom CSS style in every page which I don't want at all.

So how can achieve the desired behavior via layout updates?

### EDIT

As Kishan's answer points out, adding `media="all"` did the trick. But I would like to know how that magic happens.

Comment: This module does the job: https://github.com/quickshiftin/mage2-ordered-assets (not mine but i use it frequently)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Here is the short answer:

> Magento load all css assets into asset groups. Asset groups are created based on the css properties and which is what stands crucial for the rendering order of css assets.

---

### In Details

First of all, There are lot of things happens behind the scene. So in order to make this answer abbreviated as possible, I would love to consider an example here.

Suppose I have 2 layout files as shown below:

File: `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

and

File: `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

With that said, this is how page layout builder `build()` method looks like:

Class: `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder`

```
public function build()
{
    if (!$this->isBuilt) {
        $this->isBuilt = true;
        $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
        $this->generateLayoutXml();
        $this->generateLayoutBlocks();
    }
    return $this->layout;
}
```

`Builder::loadLayoutUpdates()` reads `defaul_head_blocks.xml` first and then reads `cms_index_index.xml`. As a result, the css assets which will be considered in the following order.

> 1. `<css src="css/styles-m.css"/>`
> 2. `<css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>`
> 3. `<css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>`
> 4. `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" />`

This data will be provided to the HEAD config generator class (`Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Generator\Head`) and in the `process()` method all the HEAD assets (This include js, css and meta etc.) will go through different processes such as adding assets, removing assets, processing meta data etc.

Addition of assets into the structure happens in `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Generator\Head::processAssets()`

```
protected function processAssets(Structure $pageStructure)
{
    foreach ($pageStructure->getAssets() as $name => $data) {
        if (isset($data['src_type']) && in_array($data['src_type'], $this->remoteAssetTypes)) {
            if ($data['src_type'] === self::SRC_TYPE_CONTROLLER) {
                $data['src'] = $this->url->getUrl($data['src']);
            }

            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $data['src'],
                isset($data['content_type']) ? $data['content_type'] : self::VIRTUAL_CONTENT_TYPE_LINK,
                $this->getAssetProperties($data),
                $name
            );
        } else {
            $this->pageConfig->addPageAsset($name, $this->getAssetProperties($data));
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Here both `$this->pageConfig->addPageAsset()` and `this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset()` will create asset groups based on the asset property and then append the assets to any one of the asset group based on its property..

**An asset property is an an array of attribute values other than `src` attribute.**

For example, in the case of the asset `<css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>`, the asset property will be `["media" => "print"]`.

Each asset group is an instance of `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection` and the method `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection::add()` is what creates the asset group creation (if needed) and assignation of assets into the groups.

So for the above scenario, 3 groups will be created.

**1. Asset Group (`[]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-m.css
>
> Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css

**2. Asset Group (`["media" => "screen and (min-width: 768px)"]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-l.css

**3. Asset Group (`["media" => "print"]`) Holds:**

> css/print.css

As you can see above since the asset property of the asset `Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css` and `css/styles-m.css` are the same (ie an empty array), both of them will be grouped together. Since this the first group asset which is created, all the assets in that group asset will be rendered first.

So in the above case, the asset rendering order will be:

> 1. css/styles-m.css
> 2. Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css
> 3. css/styles-l.css
> 4. css/print.css

---

### Another Example

Now if our css are configured in the below order:

> `<css src="css/styles-m.css"/>`
>
> `<css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>`
>
> `<css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>`
>
> `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" media="all" />`

Then the asset grouping will be like this:

**1. Asset Group (`[]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-m.css

**2. Asset Group (`["media" => "screen and (min-width: 768px)"]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-l.css

**3. Asset Group (`["media" => "print"]`) Holds:**

> css/print.css

**4. Asset Group (`["media" => "all"]`) Holds:**

> Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css

and hence the css rendering order will be:

> 1. css/styles-m.css
> 2. css/styles-l.css
> 3. css/print.css
> 4. Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css

Comment: adding media="all" dint help me. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Use as below...

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" media="all" />
```

instead of

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" />
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works please?

Comment: This worked. But could you please expalin why it works  as mentioned by Ben?

Comment: Regarding Ben's question, I think Magento includes highest resolution or all device styles after style-l and style-m CSS files. That is the reason.

Comment: @KishanPatadia Your answer works and the upvote is given. But the answer completes when someone or you explain why it happen so. Really answering "Why it is so" is what really going to help others. Thanks for your solution :)

Comment: I *think* Magento loads any assets with attributes after assets without. So because of the `media` attribute it is loaded later. Not 100% sure on that though it's something I've read on here before.

Comment: @BenCrook Yes Magento is grouping the assets with the `media` discrimination. But I couldnt find out where exactly this "separation" process happens. I am still trying to find it out. I will let everyone know if i would able to find it. Let me know any updates on this if you know

Comment: I posted it as separate question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/217133/6084

Comment: @BenCrook Please have a look on my answer. I hope that clarifies your doubt

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it make my custom css run between style-m.css and style-l.css, version magento 2.3.5-p1.