# Custom bootstrap overriding my luma theme style

Tags: magento2, styles, theme-overriding

I added the external **bootstap** in my **custom theme** I want to be it before **style-l.css** I referred [Load Custom CSS After style-l.css For Home Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217131/load-custom-css-after-style-l-css-for-home-page) but it's only working from home page, not for other, please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The thread you have mentioned in your question is doing just opposite of your requirement; i.e, it loads a static asset file after `style-l.css` and `style-m.css`.

If you want to load your CSS file before those two CSS files and in every page. You need to put your code in `default.xml` under your theme.

File : `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Now insert your bootstrap CSS file at the location `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/web/css/bootstrap.css`