# Magento2 Adding styles before style-l.css

Tags: magento2, css, custom-theme

I got the answer in this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217131/load-custom-css-after-style-l-css-for-home-page)

it's working only in the home page I needed it to work in each and every page please help me with this

Comment: Hi Punith, welcome to Magento stackExchange. It seems that, you are asking the same question again which makes this question a duplicate. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260314/custom-bootstrap-overriding-my-luma-theme-style . You can continue with the original question where you have an answer there. If it still not helping to resolve your issue, then feel free to update that question or ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

File: `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Css path: `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/web/css/custome.css`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
           <css src="css/custome.css"/>
           <css src="css/style-l.css"/>
        </head>
    </page>
```

Comment: If add the custome.css in default_head_blocks.xml it will add the ustome.css after the style-l.css but I need it before style-l.css

Comment: <css src="css/style-l.css"/> then <css src="css/custome.css"/>

Comment: i update my answer check it

Comment: @Punith please check my answer is working fine then accpet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by reordering the code in the layout manually

**THEME\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/your-custom-file.css"/>

        <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    </head>
</page>
```