# Magento 2: CSS include sequence

Tags: magento2, css, xml

If we include CSS in layout XML as below, Magento includes it after `style-l.css` and `style-m.css`.

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/custom.css" media="all" />
```

But if we include CSS as below then Magento includes it before `style-l.css` and `style-m.css`. So what is the reason for the same ?

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/custom.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

it is important to know that :

`style-m.css` generates basic and mobile-specific styles,

`style-l.css` generates desktop-specific styles (for 768px width screen and higher)

This means, when you open a Magento in **mobile device**, Magento load only styles compiled from the `styles-m.less` file, the Extra styles from the second file `styles-l.less` are compiling and loading **only** if the screen width is 768px or higher.

So when you add `media="all"` you target all devices and your file will be loaded in all devices, this why Magento place it after `style-l.css`, `style-m.css`

Comment: Do you have any info about the `order` attribute as every time I've checked that hasn't been a thing. Is it something new?

Comment: the order attribute is available in v 2.0

Comment: @Prince Can you please share some document for "order" attributre ?

Comment: I saw it a long time ago on github

Comment: The only reference I can see anywhere (Github, Stack Exchange, Core code) is an extension mentioned here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94769/what-is-the-proper-way-of-positioning-ordering-css-files-in-magento-2

Comment: I tested it and it worked without the extension, now it's no longer valid

Comment: to remove a doubt, I'll remove it from my answer

Comment: @BenCrook for css, there is no `order` property allowed. if you use it, magento will show an exception since it violates schema definition. If you want to know further about this, please ask a new question, then I will happily provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [**detailed answer here**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/217180/3535).

### The short answer is:

Magento load all css assets into asset groups. Asset groups are created based on the css properties and which is what stands crucial for the rendering order of css assets.

An asset property is an an array of attribute values other than `src` attribute.

### Example 1: Without `media="all"`

Suppose the css are configured in the below order in a layout configuration:

> `<css src="css/styles-m.css"/>`
>
> `<css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>`
>
> `<css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>`
>
> `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" />`

Then the asset grouping will be like this:

**1. Asset Group (`[]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-m.css
>
> Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css

**2. Asset Group (`["media" => "screen and (min-width: 768px)"]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-l.css

**3. Asset Group (`["media" => "print"]`) Holds:**

> css/print.css

and hence the css rendering order will be:

> 1. css/styles-m.css
> 2. Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css
> 3. css/styles-l.css
> 4. css/print.css

---

### Example 2: With `medial="all"`

Now if our css are configured in the below order:

> `<css src="css/styles-m.css"/>`
>
> `<css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>`
>
> `<css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>`
>
> `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css" media="all" />`

Then the asset grouping will be like this:

**1. Asset Group (`[]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-m.css

**2. Asset Group (`["media" => "screen and (min-width: 768px)"]`) Holds:**

> css/styles-l.css

**3. Asset Group (`["media" => "print"]`) Holds:**

> css/print.css

**4. Asset Group (`["media" => "all"]`) Holds:**

> Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css

and hence the css rendering order will be:

> 1. css/styles-m.css
> 2. css/styles-l.css
> 3. css/print.css
> 4. Magento_Theme::css/home/slider.css