# CSS stylesheet order acting inconsistently

Tags: css, styles

I have my standard styles-m and styles-l stylesheets. I also have a custom.css stylesheet that loads later than those 2.
On both staging and production everything loads in that order, but in development, styles.css loads later than the other 2.

As a result, I often don't end up with consistent results between dev and production. How can I make things load in the correct order in development?

Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/217246/75879

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the extension installed you can specify an order attribute in your css XML tags.

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_Module::css/custom.css" order="100"/>
</head>
```

You can also use the order attribute in layout XML files such as

> default_head_blocks.xml

Any css tags you don't specify an order for are treated as if they have an order of 1.

Comment: As per my experience it is perfect solution and working for me. But some time it not working due to server configuration and I faced it.

Comment: I use the porto theme. The stylesheet is being added in Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/head.phtml not in an xml. How can I change the order for that?

Answer (score -2):

There was one attribute with import CSS with XML. Please check below default_headd_blocks.xml file.

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" media="all"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

After doing the above please flush the cache once and then check the order of your CSS.
Let me know still if you have any queries.

Thanks

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: @vikram did you check the order of CSS in the browser? It's working very well.

Comment: @web master which Magento Version you used?